# TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(struct SimpleStoarge.People storage pointer)

Tags: solidity, remix

[image]

from solidity:
TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(struct SimpleStoarge.People storage pointer).
--> contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:22:9:
|
22 |         People.push(newPerson);
|         ^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Please, can you share like 'code' your entire smart contract?

Comment: I dont think you can use struct People.push, what is the logic you want to implement?